# Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js?

Tags: java, bootstrap, vaadin

[image: почему не удается загрузить bootstrap?]

версия tomcat 8.5.47, vaadin version = 7.7.14, куда копать?

Comment: Для начала проверить есть ли нужный файл в нужном месте =)

Comment: А что так много деталей?... у меня аж глаза разбегаются - даже не знаю куда смотреть.

Comment: расскажите для начала чистый у вас ваадин или может быть вы его вместе со спрингом юзаете или еще с чем. web.xml  или еще какие файлы настройки очень могли бы не помешать.